# Evaluating Logarithmic Expressions

Tags: functions, logarithms

Evaluate: $$\log_4 \left(\dfrac{1}{256}\right)$$

I am not sure how to approach this since there is nothing set equal to it.

Answer (score 1):

Really it should say "evaluate" not "solve" since, as you note, there isn't an equation, per se. Note that $\frac{1}{256} = 4^{-4}$. Can you see how to proceed?

Comment: i'm still a little unsure.  I know that to get logarithms in either exponential or log form we can use y=b^x , x=logbY

Comment: What do you know about $\log_b (b^a)$ in general (by definition)?

Comment: that logb(b^a)=alogb(b)?

Comment: Precisely and what is $\log_b b$ equal to?

Comment: logb^b= a? Is that it?

Comment: Maybe but I'm not quite sure if you're understanding correctly. $\log_b b = 1$.

Comment: Let $b, x > 0$, with $b \neq 1$.  Then $\log_b x = y$ if and only if $b^y = x$.

Comment: No I think I'm still confused.  For this model towards the question anyway.

Comment: @ashton It is a definition that $\log_b b = 1$, so particularly $\log_4(4) = 1$.

Comment: @ashton We want to find $x$ such that $$\log_4 \dfrac{1}{256} = x \Rightarrow 4^x = \dfrac{1}{256} = \dfrac{1}{4^4} = 4^{-4}$$

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$ \log_b x^n=n\log_b x $$
And
$$ \log_b b=1 $$
So now we have
$$ \log_4\left(\frac{1}{256}\right) = \log_4\left(\frac{1}{4^4}\right)$$
$$= \log_4\left(4^{-4}\right)= -4\log_4\left(4\right)=-4 $$

Comment: I would discourage you from just giving out answers like this. It's better to figure out where OP is having trouble than just giving them the solution.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, generally I do agree with you. However, sometimes people need a complete walkthrough to understand.

Comment: That's fair. Not sure why you got downvoted though :/